# How to get existing test user's email via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing live integration tests for an app that uses social authentication via Facebook. I have created several tests users in Facebook's app dashboard.

Now I'd like to get the email of my test user, but looking at Graph API documentation it returns the user's email only during creation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/app/accounts/test-users

Comment: You mean, you want to get it when reading existing test users back from that endpoint? That does not seem to be possible. What would you need this for?

Comment: @misorude Yes, that's what I want. I'm writing live integration tests for an app, that's why I need this. I'd like to avoid creating a new test user during every test run.